# 22 m.o. boy pees too often on the potty

Tags: toddler, potty-training

I give my 22 m.o diaper free time for a couple of hours a day for the last week. He poops on a potty (good boy). But he is willing to urinate on the potty every 5-10 minutes. It looks like he enjoys the new ability too much. 
Will it improve over time? Should I  train him for full 2-3 days, or he still urinates too frequently?

Thanks

Comment: Trust me when I say it is better than the opposite. Not having ANYTHING come out for two weeks is a medical disaster no one should have to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My baby girl was potty trained a few months ago and indeed in the beginning she was so "proud" of her new hability but also not mastering it completely that she went really often on the potty. I guess this is part of the training process and you have to be patient about it. All the time "lost" now is for the greater good later on. If it keeps going on, you may need to put some "rules" on it: once each hour you bring him to the potty for example, but I would just try to be patient and go with him now.

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid every hour is not frequently enough. Maybe he doesn't know how to hold it?

Comment: Well that's not maybe, that's also a physical thing: up to a certain age the body isn't mature enough to hold anything. As long as your kid keeps doing something when he's on the potty, it means his body isn't totally ready to hold it... It will hopefully soon be, and then putting him on the potty each hour will even be too often.